# keep last value of input box after submit with java script or php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i wanna keep last value of input box after submit and this is my code .
but my code dosent work

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>" />
```

should i use javascript or php ?

Comment: Are you perhaps using method="post" within your <form> tag?

Comment: If you use post, you should use `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: You also need to escape the data or your script is vulnerable to cross site scripting: `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']);?>" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your question "*should i use javascript or php ?*" doesn't mean:

> Using javascript is the best practice to fill the form fields with the previously
>   submit values?

My answer should be: no, the browser could have not the javascript.

But I think that your question is:
why my post submit values are not present into the global macro $_GET?

Of course you can use the **$_POST['name'];** entity to show the value, but this is a really bad choice:

- may be in the future you can change the form method from POST to GET
- may be in the future you want fill the form with data taken from DB
- may be you should validate your input before render the form

so you may do something like this:

- inside the PHP

  $valid = validate( $_POST );
- inside the HTML

  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $valid['name'];?>" />

Answer (score 0):

Keep these things correct:

1) in form tag you should have method="POST"

2) `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>" />`